# jQuery Datatable: Bind dropdown value

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery datatable to populate data and code is as below.

Here i am loading default set of options to each dropdown column while page load and it is working fine. But when tried to update dropdown selected value from response received from Ajax query it's not working. So would like to know way to update drodown column with ajax data.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {



    //Make a call to read eventfrmaes
    // GetEeventFrames();
    GetEnumset();
    GetAFTable();

    //define datatable
    oTable = $('#example').DataTable({

        "sScrollX": '100%',

        "sScrollXInner": "150%",
        "bSort": false,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "searching": false,
        "sScrollY": '300px',
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "info": false,
        //"bAutoWidth": false , 
       

        columns: [
                    { data: "ID", "visible": false },
                    { data: "Name", "visible": false },
                    { data: "Asset", "sWidth": "10%" },
                    { data: "Asset Name" },
                    { data: "Star Time", "sWidth": "10%" },
                    { data: "Stop Time", "sWidth": "12%" },
                    { data: "Duration", "visible": false },
                    {
                        "render": function (d, t, r) {
                            var $select = $("<select id='Causecode' class='cCausecode'></select>", {
                                "id": r[0] + "start",
                                "value": d
                            });
                            $.each(dtCauseCodes, function (k, v) {
                                var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                                    "text": v,
                                    "value": v
                                });
                                if (d === v) {
                                    $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                                }
                                $select.append($option);
                            });
                            // alert(r[0] + "start");
                            return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        //data: "Cause Code full Name"
                        "render": function (d, t, r) {
                            var $select = $("<select  id='Causecodefullname' class='cCausecodefullname' style='width:100px' ></select>", {
                                "id": r[0] + "start",
                                "value": d
                            });
                            $.each(dtCauseCodesfullname, function (k, v) {
                                var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                                    "text": v,
                                    "value": v
                                });
                                if (d === v) {
                                    $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                                }
                                $select.append($option);
                            });

                            return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "render": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
                            return '<input type="text"  id="textbox" class="txtBox">';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        //data: EventType

                        //"render": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
                        //    return '<select name="Eventtype" id="Eventtype" size="1" style="width:150px"></select>';
                        //}

                        "render": function (d, t, r) {
                            var $select = $("<select  id='Eventtype' style='width:100px'></select>", {
                                "id": r[0] + "start",
                                "value": d
                            });
                            $.each(dtEventTypes, function (k, v) {
                                var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                                    "text": v,
                                    "value": v
                                });
                                if (d === v) {
                                    $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                                }
                                $select.append($option);
                            });

                            return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                        }, "visible": false
                    },
                    {
                        //data: "Failure Mechanism"
                        "render": function (d, t, r) {
                            var $select = $("<select  id='failMech'  class='cfailMech' style='width:100px'></select>", {
                                "id": r[0] + "start",
                                "value": d
                            });
                            $.each(dtFailMechanism, function (k, v) {
                                var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                                    "text": v,
                                    "value": v
                                });
                                if (d === v) {
                                    $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                                }
                                $select.append($option);
                            });

                            return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        //    data: "Failure Mechanism Subdivision"
                        "render": function (d, t, r) {
                            var $select = $("<select  id='failMechsubd' class='cfailMechsubD' style='width:150px'></select>", {
                                "id": r[0] + "start",
                                "value": d
                            });
                            $.each(dtFailMechanismSubDiv, function (k, v) {
                                var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                                    "text": v,
                                    "value": v
                                });
                                if (d === v) {
                                    $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                                }
                                $select.append($option);
                            });

                            return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        //data: "Production Loss"

                        "render": function (d, t, r) {
                            var $select = $("<select  id='Prodloss' class='cprodLoss' style='width:100px' ></select>", {
                                "id": r[0] + "start",
                                "value": d
                            });
                            $.each(dtProdLoss, function (k, v) {
                                var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                                    "text": v,
                                    "value": v
                                });
                                if (d === v) {
                                    $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                                }
                                $select.append($option);
                            });

                            return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        //data: "Fuel Used"

                        "render": function (d, t, r) {
                            var $select = $("<select  id='Fuelused' style='width:100px'></select>", {
                                "id": r[0] + "start",
                                "value": d
                            });
                            $.each(dtFuelUsed, function (k, v) {
                                var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                                    "text": v,
                                    "value": v
                                });
                                if (d === v) {
                                    $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                                }
                                $select.append($option);
                            });

                            return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                        }
                    },
                    { data: "WebID","visible": false  },
        ]
    });





});
          
          
          
          
function GetEeventFrames() {
    var asset;
    var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $("#datepickerStartDate").datepicker("getDate"));
    var edate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $("#datepickerEndDate").datepicker("getDate"));

    $('#Eventtype').empty();
    $.each(dtEventTypes, function (key, value) {
        $('#Eventtype')
            .append($("<option></option>")
                       .attr("value", key)
                       .text(value));
    });
    

    var url = basewebapiUrl + "assetdatabases/" + getEventframeswebid + "/eventframes?TemplateName=" + efTemplateName + "&Starttime=" + sdate + "&endtime=" + edate;
    MakeAjaxRequest('GET', url, function (data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i++) {

            var Stardate = new Date(data.Items[i].StartTime);
            var Enddate = new Date(data.Items[i].EndTime);

            if (Enddate.getFullYear() != '9999') {
                var x = data.Items[i].Name;
                var strings = x.split('_');

                efwebIds[i] = data.Items[i].WebId;
//*Here I Want to add selected values which i got from ajex query to Dropdown columns like cause code, failure mechanism,  production loss etc.
                oTable.row.add({
                    "ID": data.Items[i].Id,
                    "Name": data.Items[i].Name,
                    "Asset": "AT-" + strings[1],
                    "Asset Name": "-",
                    "Star Time": Stardate.toLocaleString(),
                    "Stop Time": Enddate.toLocaleString(),
                    "Duration": "-",
                    "WebID": data.Items[i].WebId,
                   //set selected value to cause code
                    "Causecode": data.Items[i].Causecode

                }).draw();
            }

        }
    });

    alert("Load completed");

   
}
```

```html
 <div id="datatable">
            <table id="example" class="ui celled table" cellspacing="0" style="width: 650px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">ID</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Name</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Asset</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Asset Name</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Star Time</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">End Time</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Duration</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Cause Code</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Cause Code Full Name</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Comments</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Event Type</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Failure Mechanism</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Failure Mechanism Subdivision</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Production Loss</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Fuel Used</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">WebID</th>
                           
                                       
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a row that also contains dropdowns? Or are you just trying to set the selected values of existing drop downs?

Comment: The problem might be that you do not define "Causecode" associated with the columns definition so it does not know which column to render it with.